# KendoUI grid filter not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, filtering, kendo-ui

I am just starting with Kendo UI.  I have a .NET MVC Razor project that will include a Kendo Grid.  My page loads fine and looks good-the data is in the grid, but I have two issues:

1. when I click the "filter" icon, nothing happens (no pop-up, nothing)
2. when I run the page I get an error in visual studio inside the kendo.all.min.js file (`Error: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't suport this action.  Code highlighted reads "d.transport=new n.data.transports[a.type](c(h,{data:i}))"`  Running in firebug gives this error: `"n.data.transports[a.type] is not a constructor"`

I am using a Model that is of type List(CustomViewModel).  I have added the following scripts and css to my _Layout partial view:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(I tried using "kendo.web.min" and "kendo.aspnetmvc.min" in the place of "kendo.all.min" and I get the same result, but the error is in kendo.web.min.js)

My page looks like this:

```
@model List<CustomViewModel>
...
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("applicantGrid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ApplicationID);
        columns.Bound(p => p.FirstName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.LastName);            
    })
.Sortable()
.Filterable()  
.Pageable()        
)
```

My View Model looks like this:

```
public class CustomViewModel
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public Guid CustomViewModelID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I've noticed that in the Kendo examples (http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/local-data.html) the cursor is a hand when it's over the filter icon.  On my page, the cursor is an arrow when it's over the filter icon.

Sorting works fine.  I've also adjust this example a bit to get select and edit buttons working fine, but the filter just won't work.

I tried posting on the Kendo forums, but haven't gotten a response.

Comment: In layout I have:     `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.web.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: My understanding is that kendo.all.min.js takes the place of kendo.web.min.js and kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js.   I tried it with the scripts you gave, and the result is the same.  Thanks, though.

Comment: Did you add a reference to the `Kendo.Mvc.UI` namespace to the web.config?

Comment: Yes.  I added it to the web.config that is inside the views folder.  The only thing that isn't working is the filter.

Comment: I removed `web.min.js` and `kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js` and put `kendo.all.min.js` and my filters didn't work. According to http://www.kendoui.com/documentation/javascript-dependencies.aspx I think that `kendo.all.min.js` doesn't include MVC.

Comment: Okay, I replaced kendo.all.min.js with kendo.web.min.js and kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js.  I still get an error in the VS IDE, but the error is different.  "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'kendoSortable': object is null or undefined"  The error occurs in kendo.web.min.js when the page loads.  Also, the grid sorts when I click on the filter button (and the error re-appears as the page loads).

Comment: I currently have these .css and script files linked in my _layout file:      <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.web.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14012/discussion-between-pabloker-and-user1304444)

Comment: <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo.common.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo.default.min.css")" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

Add to your ASP.NET MVC layout page:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.web.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>
```

For more information see this: http://www.kendoui.com/documentation/asp-net-mvc/introduction.aspx

And download the last scripts version. Apparently earlier versions of `kendo.web.min`dont have .Filterable() option.

Comment: I had an old version of the script.  That fixed the problem.